# how to add different style for two different view in Angular?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have two view editmode:"New" and editmode:"edit" and trying to add different style for a paragraph, how to do that?

```
       <p  style="margin-left: 165px;margin-top: -23px;">===some messages---</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I really understand your question but if you want to add a different style depending on a variable you can do it with ngClass

You can use it like this

```
<p ng-class="{myClass: var}">Some text</p>
```

If the variable 'var' is == true then it will add the class 'myClass' to the paraghraph

There is more way how to use it, you can refer to the documentatation
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to be a little more specific on your question, or perhaps offer up an example.

BUT if I am reading this correctly, I'd suggest giving the separate `<p>` tags an ID and changing the properties in a CSS file. Make sure to attach the CSS file to your index.html

For more clarification, go [HERE](http://www.w3schools.com/css/) and get a better idea of how CSS can help.

If this wasn't helpful, I apologize. The question left a lot to be desired